# Can I use lucene for full text search in a file , but without creating indexes.

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

I want to do full text search in my application (where at a time I have around 1000 documents). But almost everytime these documents will be different. I want to use lucene for full text search, however without creating indexes. I do not want to maintain a separate secondary/primary memory for Indexes.

Is this possible ?And if Yes, Then what impact will I have on performance (say I will be having 1000 docs, and maximum doc of around 10-15 MB).

Also, Is there any other replacement for Lucene ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a memory-resident index using [`RAMDirectory`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html).  It should perform well in general, as long as your indexes aren't too large.  Note the warning in the docs:

> This class is not intended to work with huge indexes. Everything beyond several hundred megabytes will waste resources (GC cycles), because it uses an internal buffer size of 1024 bytes, producing millions of byte[1024] arrays. This class is optimized for small memory-resident indexes. It also has bad concurrency on multithreaded environments.

Also, yes, there are other full-text search tools out there...

Comment: Thanks a lot for d answer.

Comment: I have one  more concern. By default lucene is searching only in text files. For different kinds of files I have to use different extraction methods first to extract text. Is there any common way in lucene to do this that works for all kind of files ?

Comment: @NikitaBansal - No, that task is outside the scope of Lucene.  Tika is a pretty typical tool for extracting text from different file formats.

Comment: I have an app where I am parsing every kind of document through TIKA and searching for content in that parsed doc through Lucene. This is giving me good results with all files except for ".xml" files. I am not receiving any run time error. but does not provide me the xml file, even if the search word(s) is present in the xml file. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: I got the answer for my above question.  :-).. May be because TIKA considers the pattern as a  whole word (with a space before and after). And xml have no such concept of spaces. rather tags